# Level data for Mario or similar platform game

Tags: platformer, levels, tiled

It has become a widespread to implement a Mario-clone to practise writing platform games or in order to demonstrate how a game engine works.

For that reason I expected it to be easy to find level data for Mario.

Are the levels of Mario in a ready to use format available?

Note: Edited to narrow the scope of the question.

Comment: @kromster Any advice for narrowing the question down?

Comment: "Too broad" means that the question has too many answers. Here the problem I have, is that I can't find any sources for level data. I searched Github for Mario clones but most has don't store level data in a reusable format. Others only have level 1. 

There seems to be plenty of resources available for sprites, but level data is another matter.

Comment: Do you need _all_ the levels? What do you mean with 'reusable format'? I hope the clones you found on GitHub haven't just hardcoded the levels in there, and you would anyway need to do some "traslating" from any 'reusable format' to your language of choice and implementation.

Comment: I don't need all levels. Just more than level 1-1. By a reusable format, I mean that the level isn't hardcoded. Several of the Mario clones on Github hardcoded the first level - and therefore they only have that first level. Any format txt, json, sexp or similar format would be fine.

Comment: Two resources that contain levels for Mario in a reusable format: 
https://github.com/Secretchronicles/TSC/tree/devel/tsc/data/levels
https://github.com/Stabyourself/mari0/tree/master/mappacks/smb
The first is in xml (very verose) the second is in a custom format (see the reader in order to understand the representation used).

Comment: Are you sure Mari0 levels are really Mario Bros levels? Mari0 is a mix of Mario and Portals after all.

Comment: It seem right to me. When you start MariO choose the menu item MapPacks you can choose "Super Mario Bros - Classic Levels".
There are special "Portal" levels too.